# Constructing normals with given means, variances, and correlation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\rho$ be between -1 and 1, and $\mu_{j}$, $\sigma_{j}^{2}\, (j=1,2)$ be given. Construct $X_{1}, X_{2}$ normals with means $\mu_{1}, \mu_{2}$; variances $\sigma_{1}^{2}, \sigma_{2}^{2}$; and correlation $\rho$.

We are given the hint to let $Y_{1}$, $Y_{2}$ be i.i.d $N(0,1)$ and to set $U_{1}=Y_{1}$ and $U_{2}=\rho Y_{1} + \sqrt{1-\rho ^{2}}Y_{2}$. Then, to let $X_{j}=\mu_{j}+\sigma_{j}Y_{j}$ $(j=1,2)$, but this is just confusing me more. Are these estimators?

Answer (score 1):

These aren't estimators but rather new random variables defined by transformations of previous ones. We start with $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, which are independent and identically distributed Normal(0,1) random variables. We then define new random variables $U_1$ and $U_2$ in terms of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Finally, we define $X_1$ and $X_2$ by shifting and scaling $U_1$ and $U_2$, respectively.

The hint is giving you the answer, you just have to verify that the $X_1$ and $X_2$ constructed satisfy the properties required by the problem.

Comment: I other words, that their correlations are between -1 and 1, and that they each are $N(\mu_{j}, \sigma_{j}^{2})$?

Comment: That they are each $N(\mu_j, \sigma_j^2)$ and that that their correlation is _precisely_ $\rho$, where $\rho$ was specified beforehand.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to show this, though. I've been through the chapter a few times, and I've been looking back at other sections, and I still can't figure it out. U1 is obviously N(0,1), and U2 is a linear combination of two N(0,1) r.v.'s. I was thinking maybe I should show that the characteristic functions of X1 and X2 are the characteristic functions of a $N(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}^{2})$ distributed r.v. and a $N(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}^{2})$ distributed r.v, but that's not going anywhere.

Comment: Verify first that $U_2 \sim N(0,1)$. From there we use the fact that (it's not too hard to show) if $W \sim N(0,1)$ then $a+bW \sim N(a,b^2)$.